# Is there an easy way to see the number of houses?

Tags: banished

Since the number of houses (empty and occupied) is an important factor in managing population growth, this would be a useful piece of information to have at your fingertips. Unfortunately the Town Hall graphs don't show this.

So, is there an easy way to see the number of houses?
And if possible, their occupancy?

Answer (score 5):

It is in the Town Hall Overview tab.

So all you have to do is build a Town-Hall and select it, it'll display the number of Houses (marked as "Homes" in the image linked below) along with some other helpful information.

As far as occupancy, you get a rough estimate by looking at the number of families vs the number of homes. Generally speaking there's a 1:1 ratio.

Source: http://banished.gamepedia.com/File:Town_hall_overview.png